# CORS Error between Amazon Elastic Beanstalk express server and Netlify React App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, netlify

I am trying to deploy a React application that communicates with a backend application which is hosted on Amazon Elastic Beanstalk. However, when I deploy the two applications I get the following error: "Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://4bto.sitename.com/api/dashboard/login' from origin 'https://app.sitename.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.".

I configure CORS on my backend side;

```
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "https://app.sitename.com",
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    })
  );
```

and try to send headers like this;

```
app.options("*", (req, res) => {
  res.header(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
    "https://app.sitename.com"
  );
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PUT,DELETE");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
  res.sendStatus(204); // Send a 204 No Content response
});
```

I even try the wildcard the origin;

```
  app.use(
    cors({
      origin: "*",
      methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    })
  );
```

But nothing seems to work,
Is the deployment environments cause the issue? Or am I doing wrong with the CORS configuration, I have been trying to solve this issue more than 8 hours now.

My backend has a SSL certificate that I acquire in Amazon Certificate Manager and runs in a custom domain: "https://4bto.sitename.com/", And I use another custom domain in Netlify and use the same domain as a subdomain "https://app.sitename.com" (The sitenames are the same) and the same certification.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with my EC2 and S3 instances on AWS.
while the React app and the backend server might be configured to send / receive requests from any origin - your aws instance might not.

Im not familiar with Amazon Elastic Beanstalk, but aws usually have security groups / security policies in which you can specify which origin is allowed.
I think that will be a good place to start looking.